IIS web.config file corrupt?
New to IIS. Using IIS 7.5 on windows. I opened  web.config located in wwwwroot with a text editor (notepad) as I was curious of its content. I did not change anything but I mistakenly saved the file. Now it is a .txt file and is not recongnized. Unfortunately I can not recreate the file. How can I convert the file back to its original format?
THis is the content of the web.config file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Lasso8App" path="*lassoApp" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\System32\Lasso8ConnectorforIIS.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="bitness64" />
            <add name="lasso8" path="*lasso" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\System32\Lasso8ConnectorforIIS.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="bitness64" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Thanks

First, IIS7.5 is ancient, and not supported, and should not be used. Second, I think this question is a better fit at https://superuser.com ; SF caters to managing systems, not using systems.

The web.config file is just an ordinary XML file saved in clear text. If you mistakenly changed its file extension to .txt, then just change it back.

I know 7.5 is old but i need it in order to use Lasso, an ancient markup language.

Thanks Lex. Should the suffix be .conf or .config

Just tried it and it worked.! Thanks Lex

if solved, please add an answer and accept it (24h later), lese we will be reminded until the end of universum to solve your off-topic :D problem

i dont think it was off topic and I dont understand why problems with legacy software would not be permitted on this board. Not everybody has the means or knowledge to shift from old software the latest and greatest and, by the way, I did write that the solution given by lex worked

Just an FYI, even the latest version of IIS (10) often creates corrupted web.config files when setting up new websites.  It's been doing this for years! You have to go in and remove white spaces and re-save to make it work again, typically.  IIS does this so often, that it's just expected. If you did not create a web.config file for a site (even a static site), it creates a nice corrupted one for you! So convenient
